# Is it a good idea to invest time in the Unique card reward for a complete collection?

Tags: evilibrium

In the game Evilibrium you control creatures which battle and gain levels. You can also *evolve* creatures to a next level. There is also a collection ingame, and if you get three stars on a whole line of creatures, you'll get an unique card. The requirements for three stars are the following [source](http://evil-game.com/wiki/Collections):

- the creature has been in action – you must fight a battle, using the creature in your troop;
- the creature has been upgraded to maximum; after being evolved, the new creature -receives a half of gathered experience points;
- creature's skill has been upgraded to maximum.

It can be a bit confusing if you don't play the game, but it's very well explained in the beginning, so I understand that part (and any beginning player too, if he/she is following the tutorial).

Now is my question: is this wise to do? An unique card is very awesome and good, and cannot be obtained in any other way. But you have to spend a lot of time with lower ranked creatures. I am currently playing with a Common card (the lowest rank). The max level is normally 40, and I have been playing quite some time with it and it is currently level 23. It takes a valuable space in my load-out (1 of 5 places) and I would happily trade it for a Rare card. Is it wise to continue playing with this common card (and after that the uncommon evolvement) to obtain the Unique card, or am I better of equipping the highest possible cards, and farm crystals and buy creatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only begun pursuing the unique cards, because my Epic cards are not sufficient enough to advance to a level where I am encountering Legendary cards that I can defeat and capture.  I am strictly pursuing those unique cards which can be gained on a line where the top card is an Epic.  You have to grind in order to get top tier cards regardless of the route you take.  Going the unique route represents a welcomed change of pace. Will see if my opinions change over time.